# OWIN middleware PostAuthenticate event never fires

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have a simple example of OWIN middleware and I want to tap into the `PipelineStage.PostAuthenticate` stage via:

```
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAuthenticate);
```

The problem I have is that it never seems to hit the `PostAuthenticateRequest` event, even though the user is authenticated.

It always prints:

```
Current IIS event: AuthenticateRequest Msg: Should be Auth
Current IIS event: AuthenticateRequest Msg: Should be PostAuth
```

I can work around this by using the events in `Global.asax` or an `IHttpModule` but I would rather use the OWIN Pipleine.

**Simple example:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(owin2.Startup))]
namespace owin2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                PrintCurrentIntegratedPipelineStage(context, "Should be Auth");
                return next.Invoke();
            });
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                PrintCurrentIntegratedPipelineStage(context, "Should be PostAuth");
                return next.Invoke();
            });
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAuthenticate);

        }
        private void PrintCurrentIntegratedPipelineStage(IOwinContext context, string msg)
        {
            var currentIntegratedpipelineStage = HttpContext.Current.CurrentNotification;
            context.Get<TextWriter>("host.TraceOutput").WriteLine(
                "Current IIS event: " + currentIntegratedpipelineStage
                + " Msg: " + msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from:
[OWIN Middleware in the IIS integrated pipeline](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline)

The app is configured to use windows:

Anonymous Authentication = false

Windows Authentication = true

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
  </system.web>
  ...
```

Comment: Just guessing, but isn't the `Authenticate` stage earlier than `PostAuthenticate` and as such "wins"? From this article: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline there is a section at the bottom called `Stage Marker Rules` and point no. 4 says `The earliest stage of calls  to app.UseStageMarker wins` which seem it really does..

Comment: @IvanSivak Hi, I had a similar thinking but even with just the `app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAuthenticate);` on it's own it still outputs `AuthenticateRequest`. It's probably something obvious that I'm missing. :)

Comment: It seems that none of the `post` stages from the `PipelineStage` enum work. Non `post` are OK though. I'm not sure why. This article: http://leastprivilege.com/2012/02/02/mixing-forms-and-token-authentication-in-a-single-asp-net-application-the-details/ says that `Since there is no WIF session cookie or a FormsAuth cookie, these modules do nothing.`. Can this be related? Again just guessing. I tried your example code and I have the same.

Comment: @IvanSivak You are following my same steps. I've been through a few other articles by Dominick too. I think I'm going to go down the path of OAuth 2.0 with a mix of Windows, this way I can set claims within the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` and determine if they're authenticated in the `context.OwinContext.Authentication.User`. I'd like to know the answer to above though if someone has it. :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.CurrentNotification` is an enum type of `RequestNotification`. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.requestnotification(v=vs.110).aspx, it only has one value related to authenticate: `AuthenticateRequest`, which I believe includes PrePostAuthenticate, PostAuthenticate and PostPostAuthenticate stages.

List of RequestNotification values:

- AcquireRequestState
- AuthenticateRequest
- AuthorizeRequest
- BeginRequest
- EndRequest
- ExecuteRequestHandler
- LogRequest
- MapRequestHandler
- PreExecuteRequestHandler
- ReleaseRequestState
- ResolveRequestCache
- SendResponse
- UpdateRequestCache